# Get id of element when click ( php, jquery, ajax, javascript )

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, rss

I'm sorry, this is my first project and I'm learning a lot. So if someone can help me, I will be grateful.

I have this sidebar on my project, which contains rss links. I have to use ajax so each time when user click on any rss link, feeds will appear on screen.

This is my code for sidebar:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="well" style="width:300px; bottom: 0; top: 50px; position: fixed;">
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper" style="overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: scroll; height: 100%;">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li class="nav-header"> 
                <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#userMenu">
                    <h5><b>Subscriptions </b><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></h5>
                </a>

                <ul class="list-unstyled collapse in" id="userMenu">
                    <li><a id="id_1" href="#">Sub_1</a></li>
                    <li><a id="id_2" href="#">Sub_2</a></li>
                    <li><a id="id_3" href="#">Sub_3</a></li>
                    <li><a id="id_4" href="#">Sub_4</a></li>
                    <li><a id="id_5" href="#">Sub_5</a></li>
                    <li><a id="id_6" href="#">Sub_6</a></li>
                    <li><a id="id_7" href="#">Sub_7</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is any chance to get id for each link when any of those links are clicked ?

Or I have to write a different function where to use ajax for each id ?

Can someone show me how to use ajax on this only once, not seven times ?
I have a div in my body tag : `div id="changebodywithaxaj"` and I want to change it with properly feeds for each link.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the ID by this way, for more details and ajax part, check this fiddle, good luck.
http://jsfiddle.net/ea51y1j5/

```
$("#userMenu").children('li').click( function() {
    var rssId = $(this).children('a').attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Attach a click event listener to the `li a` elements; in the click handler you can get the id of the element click from the id property of this `this.id`. Then you can use that id as data in your ajax call. Also, pass the event object, `e`, and call `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the click from trying to follow the link -- in your case it would jump upto the top.

```
$('li a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var Id = this.id;
    // use id in ajax call
});
```

Comment: An explanation of what you're doing here would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just retrieve the value on click by using the `$('clickedEl').attr('id')`
link to jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/6ov1ydzv/

Answer (score 0):

If I underestand correctly, you want to add a click event to all the links:

```
$('#userMenu a').on("click", ajaxCall);
```

and in the click event get the id of the clicked element and call an ajax function to paint the feeds on the screen:

```
function ajaxCall(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: "url",
        data: { id : id },
        success: paintFeedsOnScreen
    })
}
```

It's that or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$('ul.list-unstyled').on('click', 'a', function() {
  var ID = this.id;
  //use the ID for your ajax call...
});
```

Even better, you could also use the element id since you have one, as below:

```
$('#userMenu').on('click', 'a', function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
  $('li a').click(function(){
    var id = this.id;
       $.ajax({
            url: // your url goes here
             data:{id:id},
             success: function(result){

          }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you only want the ID from the link click on you can do:

```
$("#userMenu li a").on("click", function(){
    var id = this.id;
    // This is where you can do what ever with your id from that element.
    return false; // This is so that it won't follow the link you're clicking and reload the page 
                  // when you don't want to.
});
```

But perhaps you actually want the href from the link you click. Since it's a link you want to follow (with ajax) any way? You'd pretty much do the same thing:

```
$("#userMenu li a").on("click", function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    // do your ajax stuff here perhaps. With href as a link in your ajax call. 
    return false; 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this code as a JS script on the page :

```
$("#userMenu a").click(function() {
    $("#changebodywithajax").html(updateRSSWithID($(this).attr('id')));
});
```

Where `updateRSSWithID(IDGoesHere)` is a function that takes in the ID of the element and returns the appropriate body of text that corresponds to it.

Comment: It's either $(this).attr('id') or better this.id;

Comment: Downvotes should ideally be removed once the error has been rectified.